# assert(false) in D language

Tags: assert, d

TDPL describes a behavior of `assert(false);` statement. Such assertion is not removed from release build (as all other assertions) and, actually, stops the program immediately. The question is why? Why such confusing behavior? They might add `halt();` or something like that to be able to stop the program.

Sometimes, I use the following construction in C++ code:

```
if (something_goes_wrong)
{
   assert(false);
   return false;
}
```

Obviously, such construction is not possible in D.

**UPDATE**

To be clear. The question is why `int x=0; assert(x);` won't crash a release version of a program, but `assert(0);` will? Why such strange language design decision?

Comment: Such a construct _is_ possible in D as long as you can make it so that the value has to be evaluated at runtime (such as calling a function which just returns `false`). Generally though, I'd argue that what you're doing there is probably not the best way to go about it. It would depend on the exact situation though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

that's older than D and it's generally used to tell the compiler you don't expect to ever get to that point in the code for because that would mean that something is very wrong in the code

typical use is like this

```
MyStruct foo(){
    foreach(s;set){
        if(someConditionGuaranteedToHoldForAtLeastOne(s))
            return s;
    }
    //now what I can't return null;
    assert(0);//tell the compiler I don't expect to ever come here
}
```

Comment: This. Questions like this often come from people who misunderstand the purpose of asserts. A failed assert means something has gone horribly wrong and something happened that should never, ever happen unless there's a bug in your code.

Comment: CyberShadow: It doesn't mean I do not understand the purpose of asserts. The question is about a language design. I just wonder why assert(x) where x is 0 won't crash my program but assert(0) will. Even if something goes completely wrong it doesn't mean that a program shall be immediately crashed.

Comment: if `int x=0;assert(x);` doesn't fail it means that you don't have asserts enabled, check the compiler flags if your compiling to debug or release version

Comment: @ratchet freak: I mean release build. `int x=0;assert(x);` won't crash the program, but `assert(0);` will.

Comment: @Stas: regarding  immediately crashing the program: IIRC the thought behind the design of assert doesn't allow that. Assert is for the cases where the program is so badly out of sorts that the only thing you can safely do is halt as fast as possible. In the cases where assert is supposed to be used, you can't even safely clean up external state because the "impossible" has already happened and the stuff you would clean up may be invalid beyond repair.

Answer (score 7):

An assertion is used to verify something about the state of your program at a particular point in the program. If the assertion fails, then there is a bug in the program, and it makes no sense to continue the execution of the program. But it *does* cost something to run an assertion - especially one that involves making function calls - so you usually disable them in release mode (`-release` for dmd does this automatically). You run your program and test it in debug mode and hopefully you hit any states that result in assertions failing so that you can catch and fix those bugs. Then you hope that you've caught them all and that nothing terribly bad happens in release mode if you didn't.

But what about entering code paths which should *never* be reached under *any* circumstances? That's where `assert(0)` comes in.

It functions like a normal assertion without `-release`, so you get nice stack traces and all that when you hit it, but because it's something that should not only never happen but would result in a completely invalid code path, it's left in in release mode but changed to a halt instruction. Classic places of where to use it would be cases such as

```
switch(var)
{
    ...
    //various case statements that should cover all possible values of var
    ...

    default:
        assert(0, format("Invalid value for var: %s", var));
}
```

where the default case should never be hit, and if it is, the logic in your function is wrong, or

```
string func(int i) nothrow
{
    try
        return format("%s", i);
    catch(Exception e)
        assert(0, "Format threw. That should be impossible in this case.");
}
```

where as long as the logic of `func` is correct, it should be impossible for it to throw, but it called a function which *can* throw under some set of circumstances (just not these), so you have to use a try-catch block to make the compiler happy. You then put an `assert(0)` in the catch block so that you catch it if it really *can* throw.

*The* classic case for `assert(0)` is actually used by the compiler itself - and that is to insert it at the end of a function which doesn't end with a return statement so that the code execution does not attempt to continue if your code's logic is incorrect and you somehow end up at the end of the function anyway.

In all such cases, you're dealing with a code path which is impossible to hit as long as your code is correct, but it's a safety net in case you got your logic wrong. The advantages of using `assert(0)` for this over a naked halt instruction are that when `-release` is enabled, you get a proper stack trace, and you can have a nice error message with it. Then when `-release` *is* enabled, it gets turned into a halt instruction, so you're *guaranteed* that your program won't get itself into an invalid state by getting past the line with the `assert(0)`.

You use normal assertions for stuff that you want to verify in debug mode but not in release mode, and you use `assert(0)` for code paths that you want to *guarantee* are never hit in *any* mode.

Comment: I understand that point. But, agree that you can't guarantee that unreachable code will be never reached. You can't prove your program correctness and can't guarantee that a number of bugs is exactly zero. So, why do you want to write a code that will crash the whole program just because something goes wrong? It won't be appreciated by a customer. Especially, if he can lose money due to that crash. There are a lot of options how to handle such situation. For example, you can throw an exception, try to save a stacktrace and send it to developers, warning a user that "system is unstable" etc.

Comment: assert(0) in D reminds me of C++ exception specifications. A language feature that can easily kill your program, so it should never be used in production code. http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm

Comment: asserts used for catching programmer's errors, not errors induced to your app by outer world (file doesn't exist etc., this is why there are Exceptions). They (asserts) should be used in cases when you can't hold app invariant, and you have two options: app halting using asserts (in debug builds it will also show you place where error was detected) or unpredictable continuation of execution. Application in second case can do anything from simple crash to (in extremely situations) some data corruption. So better when you can predict app behaviour, even if it's just a crash with error message.

Comment: If you want to do something other than `assert(0)`, there's nothing stopping you. But the idea is that if you hit it, your code is in an unstable state, and it's not safe to continue execution. So, it's better to kill the program than to let it continue. It has the advantage over halt that you get decent error messages in debug mode, and as I said, if that's not what you want to do, then handle it in some other way (e.g. throwing an Error which is caught at the top level of your program and then pops up a dialog as you suggest).

Answer (score 6):

The only reason you are able to switch off asserts in release builds, is to save time by not having to test the assert expression when it's probably just going to pass.

"false" never passes.